# “Is there...?” or “there is... .”

Tags: formality

To solve some problem, I want to confirm our partners whether we have any measures.
Is the following sentence grammatically wrong?

> “Please advise is there any procedures we can take?”

Since “please advise” should be followed by Subject+Verb, is

> “Please advise there is any procedures we can take.”

correct? Or

> “Please advise us of whether there is any procedures we can take.”

or

> “Please advise us that there is any procedures we can take.”.

Please advise.

Comment: Apart from your grammar question, usually one writes: Please advise. At the end and after the other things.

Answer (score 1):

The word "procedures" applies to all options and is plural. Therefore one should say "there are" or "are there" (depending on the word order in the rest of the sentence).

Option 1 is fine except for the lack of a comma before "is there" (the above mentioned still applies). Bare in mind that this is a very shortened way to express what you want to express here. Alternatively a ";" would also work and the rest of the sentence is just additional information on what one should advise someone.

Option 2 has the wrong word order.

In Option 3 the word "of" has to be left out.

Option 4 hardly makes any sense to me.

So TL;DR::

USE: "Please advise us, are there any procedures we can take?"

OR : "Please advise us if there are any procedures we can take?"

Answer (score 0):

“Please advise us of any procedures we can take.”